# Getting Python to Create a new instance every time

Tags: python, oop, instance

I have a class to generate data:

```
class dataGen():

        #class to generate data.

        def firstName():
                firstName = 'Storm' + str(timeGen.timeGen())
                return firstName

        def lastName():
                lastName = 'Trooper' + str(timeGen.timeGen())
                return lastName 

        def randString():
                rint = random.randint(1,20)
                r4ndString = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(rint))
                return r4ndString

        def email():
                EmailA = dataGen.randString() 
                EmailB = dataGen.randString()
                items = ['.com','.net','.org']
                tld = random.choice(items) 
                return str(EmailA) + '@' + str(EmailB) + str(tld)

        def empid(size=20, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
                return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))   

        def ssnGen():
                ssnGenD = random.randint(100000000,999999999)
                return ssnGenD
```

Class making SQL call:

```
class sqlConn():

        #Class to handle all SQL connections

        def realEmail(cEmail):
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=Dev1SQL1;DATABASE=TimeCurrent;Trusted_Connection=yes')
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                sql = 'exec tbl.usp_Lookup_Email "%s"' % cEmail
                cursor.execute(sql)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                return(data)

        def realEmpID(cEmpID):
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=Dev1SQL1;DATABASE=TimeCurrent;Trusted_Connection=yes')
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                sql = 'exec tbl.usp_Lookup_EmplID "%s"' % cEmpID
                cursor.execute(sql)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                return(data)                

        def realEmpName(cFName, cLName):
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=Dev1SQL1;DATABASE=TimeCurrent;Trusted_Connection=yes')
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                value = (cFName, cLName)
                sql = 'exec tbl.usp_Lookup_Name "%s", "%s"' % value                
                cursor.execute(sql)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                return(data)

        def realSSN(cSSN):
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=Dev1SQL1;DATABASE=TimeCurrent;Trusted_Connection=yes')
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                sql = ' exec tbl.usp_Lookup_SSN "%s"' % cSSN
                cursor.execute(sql)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                return(data)
```

...and I have a class that is calling that based on results from my SQL query.

```
def deID(HOLDERLIST):
        #Takes in the holderList from holderClass, checks aganst the database to see if the fakeFeild for each of the values has data,
        #If the feild does not return none, it uses that data.  If it is none, then it generates new data.
        for item in HOLDERLIST:
                for idx, lis in enumerate(item):                        
                        if idx == 0:
                                fName = item[0]
                                lName = item[1]
                                name = sqlConn.realEmpName(fName, lName)
                                if name == None:
                                        item[0] = dataGen.firstName()
                                        item[1] = dataGen.lastName()

                                else:
                                        item[0] = name[0][0]
                                        item[1] = name[0][1]

                        elif idx == 2:
                                SSN = sqlConn.realSSN(item[idx])
                                if SSN == None:
                                        item[idx] = dataGen.ssnGen()                                        
                                else:
                                        item[idx] = SSN                                        

                        elif idx == 3:
                                email = sqlConn.realEmail(item[idx])
                                if email == None:
                                        item[idx] = dataGen.email()
                                else:
                                        item[idx] = email                                       


        print('Holderlist deID')          
        return(HOLDERLIST)
```

My Main Loop

```
def main():

        datagenInstance = dataGen()
        SQLConnInstance = sqlConn()  
        CLIENT, filename, FILESTRUCT = selectFile()
        PARSED = parse(filename)
        HOLDERLIST = holderClass(PARSED, FILESTRUCT)
        deIDedData = deID(HOLDERLIST)
        deIDedFile = merge(PARSED, deIDedData, FILESTRUCT)
        fileExport(filename, deIDedFile)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

HOLDERLIST is just a CSV file that is parsed into a list of 4 strings.  The issue I am having, is that the SQL connection class and the dataGen class are not making new calls every time.  Every time the loop runs, it should be creating a new instance of the two aforementioned classes.  I know that in languages like c# and c++ I can affix new to the front of the call to force the language to create a new instance every time it is called.  I have read the literature on using things like **new** in python, but that seems to be placed in the class declaration and I don't really understand python's class decorations that well.

Comment: Why are any of these things classes? You're not making a single instance of these classes anywhere, and none of the methods would use any instance state or work on an instance at all if you did.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to link my main loop.  Question has been edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're not too familiar with classes in Python. You've created two classes which only contain class methods and no instance attributes. To update your `dataGen` class to be instance-based, you might use something like:

```
class DataGen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_name = 'Storm' + str(timeGen.timeGen())
        self.last_name = 'Trooper' + str(timeGen.timeGen())
        self.email = DataGen.rand_email()
        self.empid = DataGen.rand_empid()
        self.ssn = DataGen.rand_ssn()

    @staticmethod
    def rand_string():
        r_int = random.randint(1,20)
        r_string = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + 
                         string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) 
                    for _ in range(r_int))
        return r_string

    @staticmethod
    def rand_email():
        email_a = DataGen.rand_string() 
        email_b = DataGen.rand_string()
        items = ['.com','.net','.org']
        tld = random.choice(items) 
        return str(email_a) + '@' + str(email_b) + str(tld)

    @staticmethod
    def rand_empid(size=20, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + 
                                string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

    @staticmethod
    def rand_ssn():
        ssn = random.randint(100000000,999999999)
        return ssn
```

When an instance of a class is created, the `__init__` function is called and is used to instantiate the class (which usually means setting instance attributes). All instance methods are implicitly passed the parameter `self` which is the instance of the class. The decorator `staticmethod` overrides this behavior and, when these methods are called, no parameters will be implicitly passed. Creating an instance and accessing its attributes is straight forward.

```
instance = DataGen()

print(instance.first_name) # Storm8
print(instance.last_name) # Trooper6
print(instance.email) # xOy37zF@bR68DdLr36mq.net
print(instance.empid) # JhPGpnwUQlm9tCaWbW3F
print(instance.ssn) # 370469583
```

However, when you create `datagenInstance` in your main loop, it's not being used anywhere. You'll need to pass it to the relevant functions. It's hard to offer much more guidance than this as you'll likely need to restructure a lot of your code. [This link](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) may help you better explain classes.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, the way classes work in python, I need to explicitly call a reference of each method each time the class is called (the self.methodname)?  Then I just call the class reference that I instantiate in my main() ?

Comment: @AddisonWilson No, you probably want to create a new instance in your main loop and update `deID` to accept a second parameter, `DataGen_insance`.

Comment: @AddisonWilson Or maybe not, it's really unclear what you are trying to do. Do you need to be creating instances at all? If so, what information do you want to be encapsulated in an instance?

Comment: I want datagen to give me back different data each time it is called.  For instance, I want first_name to give me a different value each time it is called in DeID eg: Storm123456789 then Storm123456790 (with 123456789 being epoc time).

Comment: @AddisonWilson If you don't want data to be grouped together, then don't use a class. Just create functions for each random generator. If you want these functions to all be contained in the same area, then you can create a module with them.